# How to use 'where' with AngularFire 7 new api?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I upgraded AngularFire to 7, and have a problem with using .where with collectionReference. So simply.. how to use it properly?

I tried to use 'collection' from '@angular/fire/firestore' like:

```
const ref = collection(this.firestore, 'collectionName');
```

but the ref has not 'where' or something.

I know that '@angular/fire/firestore' has also 'query' and 'where', but I don't know how to use it.

How to find documents in the collection using 'where' with a new API?

Answer (score 13):

I managed to figure this one out...

for single where statement use

```
const refq = query(ref,where('dir','==','T'))
```

for multiple where statements use

```
const wa:QueryConstraint[] = [where('dir','==','T'),where('day','==',23)]

const refq = query(ref,...wa)
```

to get the results use

```
collectionData(refq).subscribe()
```

Comment: @Yunnosch thaks, I edited the answer to make it more accurate

Answer (score 10):

AngularFire 7.0 is based on the new tree-shakable Firebase JS SDK v9, so you should do as follows (untested):

```
const ref = collection(this.firestore, 'collectionName');
const q = query(ref, where("...", "==", "..."));
```

See the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries) (tab "Web version 9").

Answer (score 6):

AngularFire has the Firebase JS SKD v9 syntax, using their own objects:

```
import {collection, collectionData, Firestore, query, where} from '@angular/fire/firestore';

export class FooClass {

  constructor(private firestore: Firestore){
    const ref = collection(firestore, 'collectionName');
    const q = query(ref, where('ids', 'array-contains', id));
    const res$ = collectionData(q);
  }
```