# AngularFirestore Get a document by field

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

How can i get a document by field, i am already getting a document by id with this code

```
export class FileService {

  recordDoc!: AngularFirestoreDocument<Fileobject>;

  constructor(public db: AngularFirestore) {
     
  }

  getById(id: string) {
      this.recordDoc = this.db.doc(`files/${id}`)
      return this.recordDoc.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
  }
```

but i cant find how to get a document for a field "name"

i tried

```
getByName(name: string) {
   this.recordDoc = this.db.doc(`files/${name}`)
   return this.recordDoc.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
}
```

Comment: You'll need to use a query for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52071245/angular-firestore-query-to-firestore-document, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045097/how-to-use-where-with-angularfire-7-new-api and https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/compat/firestore/querying-collections.md